# How to eliminate Query error: 403 in Grafana? Example is a Substring

Tags: substring, grafana

I'm trying to receive a result similiar to '13:49:31' in this panel. Here is the code:

`select SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-3,SYSDATETIME())),12,8)`

This is the message: "Query error: 403"

I copied the code and executed it at SQL Server Management Studio and it worked.

If I remove the substring function, it works. Like this `"select CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(HOUR,-3,SYSDATETIME()))"`[image]

However, I really need this format '13:49:31'

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?